# Java Array Sorting based on multiple parameters

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array that I want to sort in ascending order. However, I want to sort them with reference to a boolean array.I would like to sort the values that are `true` in ascending order, followed by the values that are `false` in ascending order.
Little stuck on how to get there.

This is what I have currently:

```
Object[] arr = new Object[6];

arr[0] = new Object(2); 
arr[1] = new Object(5); 
arr[2] = new Object(3); 
arr[3] = new Object(1);
arr[4] = new Object(6);
arr[5] = new Object(4);

Available[] avalarr = new Available[6];

availarr[0] = new Available (true);
availarr[1] = new Available (false);
availarr[2] = new Available (false);
availarr[3] = new Available (true);
availarr[4] = new Available (true);
availarr[5] = new Available (false);
```

I need the output to be:

`1 2 6 3 4 5`

Comment: First, get both "newAvailable" and your object into a single thing to be compared, e.g. define a new object containing an instance of both.  Then, implement a custom comparator (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Comparator.html). Your "compare" method should always first check the boolean values of your new object--then the integer value. Finally, use Arrays.sort with your new single array and your new comparator.

Comment: ...though I'm not sure what you mean by "new Object(2);".  I assumed you had a class, say "Thing", that took an integer constructor: class Thing { public Thing(int value){ this.value = value; } }.  Right?

Comment: Thanks for your response it is much appreciated. I will test and see how it goes.Yes you are correct on the variables

Comment: Do you have 2 arrays? Or 1 array with filled with a class that has two attributes (1 integer, and 1 boolean)?

Comment: Currently i have 2 arrays.

Comment: Take a look at my proposed answer, all you need is a `Item` class, and an array of `Item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SelectiveSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Item [] items = new Item [6];
        items[0] = new Item(2, true);
        items[1] = new Item(5, false);
        items[2] = new Item(3, false);
        items[3] = new Item(1, true);
        items[4] = new Item(6, true);
        items[5] = new Item(4, false);

        System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
        // Removed enhanced for loop
        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(items[i].getIntValue() + " ");
        }

        // Sorting
        Arrays.sort(items);

        System.out.println("\n\nAfter Sorting:");
        // Removed enhanced for loop
        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(items[i].getIntValue() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

    private int _intValue;
    private boolean _boolValue;

    public Item(int intValue, boolean boolValue) {
        _intValue = intValue;
        _boolValue = boolValue;
    }

    public int getIntValue() { return _intValue; }

    public boolean getBoolValue() { return _boolValue; }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item otherItem) {

        // Using explicit comparison
        int boolComparison = (_boolValue == otherItem._boolValue) ? 0 :
            (_boolValue) ? 1 : -1;
        return (boolComparison != 0) ? -boolComparison :
            ( (_intValue == otherItem.getIntValue()) ? 0 :
                (_intValue > otherItem.getIntValue()) ? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Before Sorting:
2 5 3 1 6 4

After Sorting:
1 2 6 3 4 5

**Explanation:**

The idea is to let your "Item" implement `Comparable`, and override the `compareTo(Item otherItem)` function based on the desired order.
Once that is done, all you need to do is to call `Arrays.sort()` on your array of `Item`.

**Version 2 (w/o Comparable/Comparator):**

```
public class SelectiveSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Item [] items = new Item [6];
        items[0] = new Item(2, true);
        items[1] = new Item(5, false);
        items[2] = new Item(3, false);
        items[3] = new Item(1, true);
        items[4] = new Item(6, true);
        items[5] = new Item(4, false);

        System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(items[i].getIntValue() + " ");
        }

        // Sorting
        bubbleSort(items);

        System.out.println("\n\nAfter Sorting:");
        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(items[i].getIntValue() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(Item [] items) {
        int n = items.length;
        do {
            int newN = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                if(compareTo(items[i-1], items[i]) == 1) {
                    Item temp = items[i-1];
                    items[i-1] = items[i];
                    items[i] = temp;

                    newN = i;
                }
            }
            n = newN;
        } while (n != 0);
    }

    public static int compareTo(Item item1, Item item2) {

        int boolComparison = (item1.getBoolValue() == item2.getBoolValue())
                ? 0 : (item1.getBoolValue()) ? 1 : -1;
        return (boolComparison != 0) ? -boolComparison :
            ( (item1.getIntValue() == item2.getIntValue()) ? 0 :
                (item1.getIntValue() > item2.getIntValue()) ? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your assistance Guys, i generally get it.. As i said i am quite new to all this. I get a error come up when i compile the project. Any ideas? Cheers Semantic Error: Enhanced for loops (also known as foreach loops) are only supported for `-source 1.5' or greater.

Comment: Updated my answer, changed the 'enhanced for loop' to a 'normal for loop'.

Comment: Cheers. One error solved another one appeared??. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method compare(boolean, boolean) is undefined for the type Boolean
 The method compare(int, int) is undefined for the type Integer

Comment: It has to do with the Java version you are using. Anyway, updated answer. Changes are in the `compareTo` function.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance it is greatly appreciated. Works perfect. As i am reasonably new to all this is there any particular literature or courses that you would recommend? thanks again.

Comment: @Dan You can try looking for some basic Java book, or possibly online tutorials. Something like this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ?

Comment: Cheers mate. Is the an alternative to Comparable to get the same result?

Comment: @Dan you mean, an alternative to `Comparator`? I am using `Comparable` in my answer.

Comment: Yes sorry and alternate to Comparable

Comment: @Dan yes, they are roughly the same though (if I am not wrong)

Comment: Yeas i have read that they are similar however i just wanted to know if there was another way without using Comparable  or Comparator to get the same answer?

Comment: @Dan Ahhh yes, of course you can do that. You could just write a sorting algorithm on your own (e.g. BubbleSort, etc) and the conditions for swapping those items will be based on your desired order.

Comment: @Dan updated to show a version without `Comparator`/`Comparable`

Comment: Thanks that works well also. One more question instead of printing the sorted array to the console how would i access that from another class?

Comment: @Dan Pass it as an argument? Say I have this function, e.g. `doSomething(Item [] items)` that takes in an Item array.. you can pass the function the sorted array as an argument, i.e. `doSomething(items);`

Comment: @Dan just read more from the books, online tutorials, etc. The best way to learn is still to try it out yourself!

Answer (score 0):

(To expand on my comment:

You need a basic "thing":

```
class Thing {
   boolean newAvailable;
   int order;
   public Thing(boolean newAvailable, int order) {
      ...
   }
}
```

...and a Comparable...

```
class CompareThings implements Comparator<Thing> {
    ...
    int compare(Thing t1, Thing t2) {
        if (t1.newAvailable!=t2.newAvailable)
            return t1.newAvailable==true ? 1 : -1;
        return t1.order-t2.order;
    }
}
```

(Note that t1.newAvailable==true is redundant, but I think it clarifies what's going on here.)

Now build an array of Thing and call Arrays.sort(Thing[] things, CompareThings);